# Zero score answers ranked before positive voted ones

Tags: support, answers, sorting, score

I just realized that answers that have 0 scores are ordered before other answers that have one or more votes. Is this a new feature to promote new answers or a bug?

### Examples

- [CSS : Background-color on multi-line text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709313/)
- [How to use pointer expressions to access elements of a two-dimensional array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554244/)
- [Manage Sub-variables in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828148/)

### Pictures

> [image: Answer ordering bug]

---

> [image: Another answer ordering bug]

---

Comment: How many screenshots did u use to create these ones?

Comment: @nicael, there are browser extensions that allow grabbing the entire page at once.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I think it was a good lesson, and you deserve the repz.

Comment: @nicael I used [Nimbus for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/hu/firefox/addon/nimbus-screenshot/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have sorted by "active". Sort by "votes" instead.

> [image: Sort by votes]

Comment: Ooooh. What a fail...

Comment: @totymedli you probably misclicked at some point without noticing, the selection is permanent, so it's really not trivial. Happens to the best! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Now I look like a noob (._. ) and I can't even wash away this shame from my questions list with a delete button.

Comment: Well this is a dupe after all so you can flag for mod attention, @totymedli, and they might agree to delete if you really want. (or ProgramFOX can simply delete the answer, giving up the repz, then you can delete yourself)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't want to takeway his repz. The misfortune of one is the luck of the other.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not able to because my answer is accepted. It's now up to totymedli whether they unaccept my answer or keep it.

Comment: @ProgramFOX It was a good lesson. But your and InfiniteRecursion's attitude on placing the community before your rep and your kindness is a honor for me, so thanks!

Comment: @totymedli You're welcome!

Answer (score 8):

You can sort by:

- Active: Recently modified one will be towards the top
- Oldest: First posted answers will be towards the top
- Votes: Posts will be sorted by votes in descending order. Answers with more votes will appear towards the top.

Select the "votes" tab to sort the answers by votes.